# Thousand of messages in Event Viewer

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, system-administration

I have a web service running in IIS, there are no errors being thrown and everything works great. BUT I notice that there are thousands of Messages in the Event viewer. Every time I send a request to the web service, a few of this messages are added to the Event viewer.

Even Type = Information
Event ID = 0
Category = None
Source = /LM/W3SVC/******/WebServiceName/**********
Description =  Loaded config from: E:\inetpub\MyWebServicePath\web.config

Why is IIS logging all this messages in Event Viewer, this is adding a lot of noise, The Event ID = 0 means ERROR_SUCESSS, which means that the operation was completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in

in your web.config

is there an entry there for System.ServiceModel?
That will cause a lot of logs to be added.